# How to prevent Request-IP replacement when using RemoteIpValve in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

I want to make use of the `RemoteIpValve` in a `tomcat8` webserver.

Problem: as a result, the `request.remoteAddr` (which was 127.0.0.1 before) is updated with the external calling ip. And thus, the `RemoteAddrValve` rejects it as it seems as if an external direct access occured.

Question: how can I still forward the "real" external IP to tomcat, leave tomcat accepting only local requests, but also make use of `RemoteIpValve`?

Tomcat is configured to allow only local access through the `apache2 proxy` in front:

`context.xml`:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"/>
```

As I still want to read the real request, eg if it was a http or https request etc, I'm forwarding those fields in apache2, and enabled the evaluation in tomcat in `server.xml` with:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" remoteIpHeader="X-Forwarded-For" protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto" />
```

As a result, anything beside localhost requests get rejected with `403 forbidden`. This is because tomcat replaces the callers real IP, and `RemoteAddrValve` rejects it then of course.
How can I prevent this?